# How to add properties to ColdFusion exception object

Tags: exception, coldfusion

I know this must seem like a very contrived example, but I have a case in which within a catch I will be try/catching another exception.  However, I would like to include information in the second catch about the first exception.  Ideally it would look something like this:

```
try {
  a = b;
}
catch ( any e ) {
  local.originalException = Duplicate(e);
  try  {
     throw "New exception!!!";
  }
  catch( any e )    {
     e.originalException = local.originalException;
     doNotification( e );
  }
}
```

When I run this little test, there is no unexpected exception that occurs when setting e.originalException, however, when I dump the exception immediately after setting it, it is not a part of the exception struct.  Is there perhaps another way to achieve this?  I am using ACF 9.

Answer (score 3):

You can't really "attach" much additional info to a CF exception, unfortunately.  But you *could* do something like this to wrap up one exception in another one...

```
<cftry>
<cfset a = b>
<cfcatch>
    <cftry>
        <cfthrow message="new exception" extendedinfo="#serializeJson(cfcatch)#">
        <cfcatch>
            <cfset stOriginalExceptionData = deserializeJson(cfcatch.extendedInfo)>
            <cfdump var="#stOriginalExceptionData#">
        </cfcatch>
    </cftry>
</cfcatch>
```

Does this sort of technique help you?

Comment: I will consider this, but unlike my contrived example, I will not be manually throwing a second exception.  I will am using a 3rd party JAR from another business unit that throws Java exceptions based on specific results as I post to an ESB.  I would essentially have to catch the outer exception, catch the inner exception, and then throw my own.  This has a very clunky feel to it, but my choices are limited.  Just voted on your submitted catch bug btw. http://cfbugs.adobe.com/cfbugreport/flexbugui/cfbugtracker/main.html#bugId=83654.  Adobe really needs to address this.

Comment: Yeah, I know... but the only way I know of getting one's own info into an exception object is to raise an exception.  I dunno if it would help, but instead of throwing the exception, you could just create one:
    
    <cfset oException = createObject("java", "coldfusion.runtime.CustomException").init("type", "message", "detail", "errorcode", "extendedinfo")>

Comment: (apologies for the lack of coherent formatting there.  I tried, but... well... this site's software ain't the best in that particular area...)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try duplicating the object? Because according to the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ec5.html) you cannot modify cfcatch exceptions:

> Changed object modification: you cannot modify the object returned by
>   cfcatch

Comment: I actually added Duplicate() about 15 minutes before your comment and there was no difference in the result.  I think what I may end up having to do is to create a completely custom exception by instantiating an instance of java.lang.Exception.

Comment: BTW, I think I have found in my testing that catch() isn't thread-safe at all.  I just wrote this: http://daveshuck.com/2011/11/02/coldfusion-9-catch-is-not-thread-safe/

Comment: (Edit) Yeah, I was afraid of that. But at least it jives with what the documentation says. From the updates on your blog entry, the bug report if people want to vote for it: http://cfbugs.adobe.com/cfbugreport/flexbugui/cfbugtracker/main.html#bugId=83654

Comment: BTW: I think `java.lang.Exception` is the way to go. At least then you could chain the exceptions. I really cannot think of a better option.